# Which is the smallest chess engine with ELO at least 2000?

Tags: engines

Preferably written in javascript, but the language really doesn't matter.

Comment: "Smallest" like least code? There is a very "small" engine, but it is heavily obfuscated and I'm not sure about the strength: http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/max-src2.html

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/chess-mini/id616424231?mt=8

Comment: http://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/chess-mini

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster, awesome! another in C, nanochess: http://www.ioccc.org/winners.html (again not sure on strength).

Comment: Micromax beats nanochess easily as reported on talkchess.com a while ago. Nanochess is small, but not a serious attempt to make it truly playable. MicroMax's derivative - FairyMax has been bundled with the Winboard package, it's a very popular engine.

Comment: Nanochess can win against Fairy-Stockfish 14 level 3 (1400 Elo) on lichess but loses against level 4 (1700 Elo)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any "small" chess engine written in JavaScript, but there's a "small" engine written in C. Micro-max has about 1900 to 2000 rating, depends on the rating list and testing condition.

http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/cgi/engine_details.cgi?print=Details+%28text%29&eng=Micro-Max%204.8

Note that it's not the smallest engine, but the engine that is even smaller than Micro-max plays awful chess (dropping pieces) and even walk into check (illegal move).

Answer (score 2):

Garbochess-JS is written in javascript.  It's about 75KB, 2400 or so lines of code I believe.  The version written in C++ was rated around 2575 on CCRL.

https://github.com/glinscott/Garbochess-JS

Lozza-js is rated around 2300, and is about twice the size of Garbochess-JS.

Toledo Nanochess and P4wn are probably less than 2000 elo, and Stockfish-js is considerably larger than Garbochess and Lozza.

Comment: And stofish js is not really JS but compiled WASM

Answer (score -1):

t seems like garbo was a little stronger maybe 2670 but anywhoo.

https://jtiscione.github.io/chessboard3js/play.html is a nice online interface for playing p4wn -weak lozzo -strong!! and stockfish -godlike

http://op12no2.me/toys/lozza/play.htm

Answer (score -1):

http://forwardcoding.com/projects/ajaxchess/chess.html <--garbo chess

http://htmlchess.sourceforge.net/demo/example.html <-- 2d-3d chess